# Running through a Tree in Java

Tags: java, recursion, tree

Basically I want to write a function that, given a Decision Tree, prints all the possible paths in the tree, and for each possible path, also prints a list of boolean values (true or false), indicating if it went left(true) or right(false) in the tree.

Here's my Tree type:

```
public class Tree {

private TreeNode root;


private static class TreeNode {
    private Pair<String, Float> data;
    private TreeNode leftNode;
    private TreeNode rightNode;

    private TreeNode( Pair<String, Float> data, TreeNode left, TreeNode right) {
        this.data = data;
        this.leftNode = left;
        this. rightNode = right;
        }
    }
}
```

Here's what i've managed to do so far:

```
private void getTreePaths(TreeNode r, List<Pair<String, Float>> list,
        List<String> flags) {

    if (r == null)
        return;

    // adds the node to the list
    list.add(r.data);

    // goes left
    if (r.leftNode != null) {

        //went left
        flags.add("true");
        getTreePaths(r.leftNode, new ArrayList<Pair<String, Float>>(list), flags);
    }

    //instead goes right
    else if (r.rightNode != null) {
        //went right
        flags.add("false");
        getTreePaths(r.rightNode, new ArrayList<Pair<String, Float>>(list), flags);
    }

    else if (r.leftNode == null && r.rightNode == null) {
        System.out.println(list.toString());
        System.out.println(flags.toString());
        return;
    }
}
```

My problem is that this only prints the first path.

How can i fix this ?

Comment: How are you invoking `getTreePaths()`? Are you attempting to solve the problem recursively? If so, there is no recursion in your code.

Comment: @BassemDy yes my idea is to do it recursively!

Comment: @queryMaster You need a recursive function which would return a path on arrival in every leaf node. Boolean values are a bit confusing... I guess strings "left" and "right" would be better

Comment: @Suspended if you notice, that's exactly what i'm using :) However i'm having trouble getting those values right...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is getTreeRules? Is that supposed to be getTreePaths? You need to call back into the function for every node.

Edit for your last question in comment:

Your flag list is accumulating because you're adding left and then keeping that when you go right. You could try something like:

```
private void getTreePaths(TreeNode r, List<Pair<String, Float>> list,
        List<String> flags, boolean lastmove) {

    flags.add(lastmove);

    if (r == null)
        return;

    // adds the node to the list
    list.add(r.data);

    // goes left
    if (r.leftNode != null) {

        //went left
        getTreePaths(r.leftNode, new ArrayList<Pair<String, Float>>(list), flags, true);
    }

    //go right
    if (r.rightNode != null) {
        //went right
        getTreePaths(r.rightNode, new ArrayList<Pair<String, Float>>(list), flags, false);
    }

    if (r.leftNode == null && r.rightNode == null) {
        System.out.println(list.toString());
        flags.remove(0); //remove first element because you passed in false value with root
        System.out.println(flags.toString());
        return;
    }
}
```

Comment: You may also need to change the "else if go right" to another if without the else, otherwise you'll miss those paths.

Comment: However the flags list is not printing quite right, it's accumulating all the values. How can i change that ?

Comment: It does not because `TreeNode` is the root node when the function is first called

Comment: if you want, you can just first call the method and put in true or false, and then when you go to print out flags.toString, first delete the first element.